# How to select only one list from listview using checkbox?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 5 list item in listview with check box. how to set user can able to select only one item using check box?

Comment: Share with us what have you tried so far?

Comment: if i selected one item from listview that items check box alone setchecked true the remaining items check box should setchecked false at a time

Answer (score 0):

Use listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

refer : [Custom ListView with single choice selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812809/custom-listview-with-single-choice-selection)

Answer (score 0):

you can read more about listview and custom ArrayAdapter

and refer to [LINK1](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) Or [LINK2](http://developerandro.blogspot.com/2013/09/listview-with-checkbox-android-example.html)

and to choose one item only can use:

```
listview .setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```